# Communicate between views from different fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, androidx, android-viewmodel

Ok so imagine two fragments, one BrowserFragment with a WebView and one BookmarksFragment which contains a list of bookmarks and a button to add new ones.

If I click on the AddBookmarkButton, I have to call getUrl on the WebView in the BrowserFragment and pass it back to the BookmarksFragment.

If I click on a bookmark in the list, I have to call loadUrl on the WebView.

What would be the best practice to achieve this in AndroidX? I read the [Fragments Communication Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate) but I don't think this is achievable using a ViewModel.

I think it's possible using fragmentManager.setFragmentResult and setFragmentResultListener but I don't know if that's the best way to do it..

Or I could just get the BrowserFragment using findFragmentByTag but afaik that is bad practice no?

Comment: Why don't you think this is doable with a ViewModel? An activity level view model shared between the fragments sounds exactly like what you need here.

Comment: Do I have to create a currentUrl variable in the ViewModel and update it every time the user navigates? It's not possible (via ViewModels) to call webView.getUrl from the other fragment directly right? And for the loadUrl part I could just use a MutableLiveData<String> requestLoadUrl variable, observe it in the BrowserFragment and call loadUrl if it changes?

Comment: Correct, the right way to use a ViewModel is to have your app's mutable state stored in the ViewModel, not in an view in an activity or fragment. The activity/fragment should observe the state in the view model (e.g. using LiveData), update displayed views when state changes, and send state updates to the ViewModel with method calls. It sounds like you are on the right track with your description.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think it's clear now!